# Calculate the following integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $\gamma_k=\{ke^{ik\theta}:0\le \theta \le 2\pi\}$ for $k=1,2,3$.Which of the following are correct?

- $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma_k}\dfrac{1}{z}=0$ for $k=1,2,3$.
- $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma_1}\dfrac{1}{z}=1$
- $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma_2}\dfrac{1}{z}=4$
- $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma_3}\dfrac{1}{z}=3$.

$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}$ has  a  pole of order $1$ at $z=0$ which is an interior point of $\gamma_k $ for $k=1,2,3$.

By Residue Theorem, $\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\gamma_k}\dfrac{1}{z}=\text{Res}(f,0)=1$.

Hence only $2$ is correct .Rest are false.

But the answer says $4$ is also true.Where am I wrong?

Comment: Consider the winding number of $\gamma_3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let me call $g(z)\equiv 1$. By Cauchy's theorem we have:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{g(\xi)}{\xi-z}d\xi=I_\gamma(z)g(z)$$

where $I_\gamma(z)$ is the winding number, so number of times you are turning around the point $z$. Observe that when $z=0$ you have

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{1}{\xi}d\xi.$$

In the case of $\gamma_3$ you turn around the $z=0$ three different times, so:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_3}\frac{1}{\xi}d\xi=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma_3}\frac{g(\xi)}{\xi-0}d\xi=I_{\gamma_3}g(0)=3.$$